# setAdapter not recognize in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have a tutorial video, in Video teacher can use setAdapter as you see below Image, but in my code, android studio not Recognize it

image of teacher learning:
[image]

and below is my code screenshot:
[image]

Comment: it is with lower case v. Read the compile time error and try to understand what it means before posting it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
ViewPager.setAdapter(...
```

with

```
viewPager.setAdapter(...
```

ViewPager (with a capital letter) is a class name and by using it here, you are trying to access the static method of that class. There is no static method `setAdapter` and hence the error.

For readability, replace `viewPager` with `pager`. It will make it easier for you to avoid such mistakes and the code will be more readable :-)

Answer (score 1):

Write `viewpager.setAdapter` instead of `ViewPager.setAdapter`

By writing `ViewPager.setAdapter` you try to execute class method, not object method. But ViewPager.class has no such method, only instance of it.